# How to send a location on android app to server?

Tags: android, apache, location, latitude-longitude

My project is create application on android. It can get a location(latitude,longitude) via GPS.After that I want to send a location to a server or web server to collect for calculate a distance which are draw on my own map(may be make from Flash) on a website.
I knows an android have apache, but I don't really know in detail about server, web server, apache.So, I want to know how to send a location from my application to server.
Anyone can help me or suggest me?

Appreciate,
Daisy

PS. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing both the Android part of the application and the server part, then you can decide how to transmit the data. You could go with some simple JSON like:

```
{"lat":12.34,"lng":56.78}
```

No reason to come up with anything more complicated than that if you don't have to.

Comment: Can I code in my application on android? Could you please post some source for me? Thank you

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html

Comment: Can i send by using variable for example:
x=-1.2222
{"lat":x}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its necessary to have apache server on server side,

AFAIK> ***android can ping to any web service on any web server. I can ping an asp web service that can be hosted on IIS.***< AFAIK

You can ask the developer of that site to develop web service (api url) that can accept latitude and longitude as parameter (or search the api if they have one `(a la google maps case)`) and you only have to care about calling that web service.

Comment: I think I need server. I do not use google map because I want dev my native country only,so that is reason why I create map. Moreover I want to do some process and create a database on server and create my website to show result.If I think incorrect, can u suggest in detail? Thanks

Comment: 1.The google map is just a reference, you don't have to use that, i wanted to tell you that there are sites who offers api to developers. 2. Yes you have to develop the site, either you develop it or you hire a dev to do this, but Can you please explain what you have said (`I want dev my native country only,so that is reason why I create map`) , for me it is bit unclear.

Comment: In my idea, I will draw a map in Flash program. When I get a location from a server. I will plot a location then draw a path on a map.

Comment: This is what i have understood : 1. You want to show a path on map using your android applocation. 2. In the country where you live google maps is banned. `OR` You have already developed a falsh app that you want to run in android. Is my assumption true?

Comment: In android application, just login(user&pass from an account which user join in the web) then get a location. The map is appear on web application only not on an android.